# How to use different fonts in footnotes and bibliography / special old hebrew

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, luatex, biber, hebrew

Im using for old hebrew and old greek text special fonts with fontspec. How can i use this also in the footnotes and in den bibliography? There are only single hebrew words in 3 of the booktitle.

Im using Lulatex and Biblatex with biber.

I found a way to set the complete bibliography in Esra SIL with

> \renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\hebfont}

but this gives me an error

> /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \bibfont already defined.

```
\documentclass[twboside=false, fontsize=12bp]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5} 
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
\newfontfamily\hebfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Ezra SIL}
\newcommand{\textheb}[1]{\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\hebfont #1\egroup}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{SBL Greek}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\bgroup\greekfont #1\egroup}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\hebfont}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=geschichtsfrkl,
pagetracker=true, 
backref=true,
]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{xy.bib}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}

\begin{Document}
\textheb{some hebrew text, works fine here}
footcite[vgl.][51]{book1}


\printbibheading[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\printbibliography[keyword=primaer,heading=subbibliography,title={Textausgaben und Hilfsmittel}]
\printbibliography[keyword=sekundaer,heading=subbibliography,title={Sekundärliteratur}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it work just to use your `\textheb` command in the titles in your `.bib` file?

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I didnt understand, that i can write format-commands into the .bib-file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Hebrew font in the bibliography by using your well-defined `\textheb` command directly in the `.bib` file itself.

Comment: can you give an example: You can get the font in the bibliography by using your well-defined  command directly in the .bib file itself.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi E.g., `@Book{key, author={Name}, title={\textheb{...}}}`